# Git Repository and msysgit Checkout?

Tags: git, msysgit

- I have installed git on an ubuntu 14 LTS Server Edition via `apt-get`
- I installed putty, pageant, plink.exe and msysgit on my Windows machine on C:\Tools
- I set system environment variable `GIT_SSH = C:\Tools\plink.exe`
- I created a user git

`adduser --system --shell /bin/bash --group --disabled-password --home /home/git git`

- I gave `chown git /usr/bin/git`
- I generated a private and public key, moved the public key on to `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, added the private key to pageant. I can login via public key authentication on the ssh server.
- On my Ubuntu machine, I have created the git repository

`mkdir /source
 cd source/
 git init --bare testprojekt.git
 chown -R git testprojekt.git/`

- I created a testfolder and a test.txt inside of the new empty repository
  `cd testprojekt.git/
  mkdir testfolder
  cd testfolder/
  touch test.txt
  echo "content" > test.txt`
- On my windows machine in Git-Bash, I executed
  `git config --global user.name "my name"
  git config --global user.email"my email"
  cd /C/Source/ #future working directory
  git clone ssh://git@<FQDN>:<Port>/source/testprojekt.git
  cd testprojekt/
  git fetch origin`

The fetched repository is empty. How do I get the testfolder and test.txt to be checked out into the working directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the list of steps you have provided, it looks like you have not actually committed anything from your Ubuntu machine.

[Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository)